# Need both ActionBarSherlock and appcompat-v7 in a project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

Please, help. I need both libraries in an android project and appcompat must be version 24.0.0 or higher. MultiDex and changing targetSdk version didn't help.

Comment: Is there any reason in having ActionBarSherlock instead of a Toolbar?

Comment: The project is very large, so it would be very difficult to use anything instead of ActionBarSherlock and sadly both libs are needed.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock has been discontinued for three years. Please stop using it. Beyond that, what exactly is your problem? You say a few things "didn't help", but you have not explained *exactly* what is stopping you from doing what you want to do.

Comment: I want to use OneSignal for push notifications and it demands appcompat 24.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. Just used com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0 instead os appcompat-v7.